# Pandas read_csv can leave file locked on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pandas

Is this a known bug and does it occur only on Windows?

With a badly formed csv file (Python 2.7.12, Anaconda 4.2, Windows 7)...

```
A,B
1,2
3,4
,5,6
```

Which will force a parsing error on the last line.

```
import pandas
import os
try:
    data = pandas.read_csv(r'input\test.csv')
except:
    print 'Bang'
os.rename(r'input\test.csv', r'output\test.csv')
```

Results in bitter complaints from windows about a locked file (by another process - I count only one but hey).

Whereas taking care of the file handle ourselves...

```
import pandas
import os
try:
    with open(r'input\test.csv','rb') as fh:
        data = pandas.read_csv(fh)
except:
    print 'Bang'
os.rename(r'input\test.csv', r'output\test.csv')
```

Doesn't lock the file.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Shobeir - good point, amendment made.

Comment: Can't reproduce, this works fine for me, I'm using python 3.4, pandas 0.19.1 and windows 7 pro

Comment: @EdChum - to be clear did you get an exception/error when parsing the file but no complaints about the file being locked or no errors of any kind?

Comment: It printed 'Bang', but still successfully renamed the file on the next line `os.rename`

Comment: So it may have been fixed as I'm using pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: I'm running pandas 0.24.1 on python 3.6.8, so I can confirm that this bug is not fixed. Interestingly though, writing another file releases the lock on the first file, so one can workaround it also by writing to a dummy file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas==1.2.1` This solved the issue for me.